# POST with custom headers using Request Library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a POST request to Expo's servers using the `request` library for JS.

Expo requires that certain headers be added, and so I went ahead and added them in a dictionary called `headers`.

```
    expoPushURL = "https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send";

    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json", 
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
        "content-type": "application/json"
    };

    data = JSON.stringify({
        "to": "ExponentPushToken[myDeviceToken]", 
        "sound": "default", 
        "title": "hello", 
        "body": "Hello world!"
    });

    options = {
        url: expoPushURL, 
        headers: headers, 
        method: "POST", 
        body: data, 
        json: true
    };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("Response from request: ",response);
        console.log("Error from request: ", error); 

    });
```

The callback is returning an undefined object. The request module has been imported without any problems. What am I doing wrong?

I am getting this error message:

```
Error from request:  { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND exp.host exp.host:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'exp.host',
  host: 'exp.host',
  port: 443 }
```

These "settings" or parameters work perfectly fine when I use `curl` or Python's `requests` library, but I need this solution to be in JS. With that said, I am sure that means there is something wrong with my code.

EDIT: The related curl would look like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send -d '{
  "to": "ExponentPushToken[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]",
  "title":"hello",
  "body": "world"
}'
```

Comment: And what is returned in error parameter?

Comment: Based on the error, the hostname cannot be found. Are you on the same network as the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have problem with headers, they are working correctly, something else is missing. What is your curl?

I have run your code against my dummy server, which returns in body all interesting values that he accepted. With this code

```
const expoPushURL = "http://localhost:3099";

const headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "content-type": "application/json"
};

const data = JSON.stringify({
    "to": "ExponentPushToken[myDeviceToken]",
    "sound": "default",
    "title": "hello",
    "body": "Hello world!"
});

const options = {
    url: expoPushURL,
    headers: headers,
    method: "POST",
    body: data,
    json: true
};

import * as request from 'request';
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body.received);
});
```

I got this response

```
{ body: '"{\\"to\\":\\"ExponentPushToken[myDeviceToken]\\",\\"sound\\":\\"default\\",\\"title\\":\\"hello\\",\\"body\\":\\"Hello world!\\"}"',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: 
   { accept: 'application/json',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     host: 'localhost:3099',
     'content-length': '115',
     connection: 'close' },
  url: '/' }
```

If someone would be just interested, the server I am using is having this code

```
const http = require('http');
const _ = require('lodash');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    const { headers, method, url } = request;
    let body = [];
    request.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(err);
    }).on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        let bodyToSend = JSON.stringify({
            alwaysHere: 'Always here',
            received: {
                body,
                method,
                headers,
                url,
            }
        });

        if (body) {
            body = JSON.parse(body);

            if (body && _.isObject(body.control)) {
                const control = body.control;
                if (_.isNumber(control.statusCode)) {
                    response.statusCode = control.statusCode;
                }

                if (_.isArray(control.headers)) {
                    control.headers.forEach(header => {
                        response.setHeader(header.name, header.value);
                    });
                }

                if (_.isString(control.body)) {
                    bodyToSend = control.body;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!response.hasHeader('content-type')) {
            response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        }
        response.write(bodyToSend); // write a response to the client
        response.end(); // end the response
    });
}).listen(3099);
```